# Localisation in the same locale?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Depending of a the context of use, I need to “translate” some words in the same locale.

An example :

- in context1, the word “team” is translate as "team"
- in context2, the word “team” is translate as "group"
- in context3, the word “team” is translate as “troop”

What is the best way to do that with the localisation functions of cakephp 3 ?

I can use :`I18n::setLocale('context1');` ?

Thanks

Comment: What does that mean, "_translate in the same locale_"? It sounds like you want to use `__x()`, but the title is rather confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change locale for context. The locale always refers to the current translation. Context is a language problem.

From the manual:

> Sometimes translations strings can be ambiguous for people translating them. This can happen if two strings are identical but refer to different things.  For example, ‘letter’ has multiple meanings in English. To solve that problem, you can use the __x() function:

So you would write:

```
 echo __x('as team', 'team');
 echo __x('as group', 'team');
 echo __x('as troop', 'team');
```

CakePHP will write a message to the translation file to indicate what the context is.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-translation-functions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me to find the solution : __d